# How to Go Inside the Object/JSON - React Next.JS - Objecj Inside de ID(Object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My JSON is this:

```
{
   "quoteId":"7ab6cb9f-f1a9-4484-aee7-686ba6f7e7a8",
   "groups":{
      "group1":{
         "pickup":{
            
         },
         "pickupExceptions":[
            
         ],
         "shipment":{
            "20b65e13-629b-4a40-8586-04360c4fdb18":{
               "id":"20b65e13-629b-4a40-8586-04360c4fdb18",
               "method":"Economics",
               "methodId":"123",
               "price":192.58
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

<-- next to the shiment prop -> This prop, change every call!-->

I try different ways, but cant access de prop: Price:

This is the last try...

```
<span>QuoteId: {quotationData}</span> <br />
            <br />
   {quotationDataComplete.map((quote) => (
              <div className={styles.card} key={quote.groups.group1.shipment}>
                <span>Price: {quote.price}</span> <br />
                   <br />
              </div>
            ))}
```

I try Like This

```
<div className={styles.card} 
key={quote.groups.group1.shipment}>
key={quote.shipment}>
<span>Price: {quote.price}</span> <br />
<span>Price: {quote.groups.group1.shipment}</span> <br />
<span>Price: {quote.shipment.price}</span> <br />
```

No one works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const quote = {
   "quoteId":"7ab6cb9f-f1a9-4484-aee7-686ba6f7e7a8",
   "groups":{
      "group1":{
         "pickup":{
            
         },
         "pickupExceptions":[
            
         ],
         "shipment":{
            "20b65e13-629b-4a40-8586-04360c4fdb18":{
               "id":"20b65e13-629b-4a40-8586-04360c4fdb18",
               "method":"Economics",
               "methodId":"123",
               "price":192.58
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

let shipment = quote.groups.group1.shipment;
// Now as `shipment` still is an object, you need to traverse it further
shipment = Object.values(shipment)[0];

console.log('Price:',shipment.price)
// Result
// Price: 192.58
```

[image]

We can do it one line as:

```js
const shipment = Object.values(quote.groups.group1.shipment)[0];

console.log('Price:',shipment.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's actual JSON and not just a JSON-like structure in Javascript you will need to Parse it `JSON.parse(jsonString);` if it's in a separate file you will need to read that file first you can do that via a `let quote = require('quote.json')`

Then you can use it as a full Javascript Object like any other. if it's already in memory you would not need to do the require but the code below would still be the same.

```
<div className={styles.card} 
key={quote.groups.group1.shipment}>
key={quote.shipment}>
<span>Price: {Object.values(quote.groups.group1.shipment)[0].price}</span> <br />
```

However, I would assume with the way this is setup you would actually want to loop thought them.

so you would want something more like

```
<div>
    {quote.groups.group1.shipment.map( (val, guid) => {
        return (
            <div className={style.card} key={quote.groups.group1.shipment[guid].price}>
                <span>Price: {Object.values(quote.groups.group1.shipment)[0].price}</span>
            </div>
    </div>
        )
    }
</div>
```